# Alt beacon lib continuously fires enter and exit region method where the user never left beacon zone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, background-service

[### Expected behavior

That the lib should only fire exit when beacon has actually exited the region.

#### Actual behavior

The lib fires exit and enter region methods where the beacon is still in range. And this happens 20 sec apart some time more frequent some times less frequent on all android versions from 5-7

#### Steps to reproduce this behavior

I am running the beacon app continuously in the background as soon as the bluetooth gets turned 
ON to search the beacon ,the beacon is fixed inside a car and is broadcasting at 1000s interval i have to start a ride when ever a user gets in the range and stop the ride when ever it gets out of it but the issue is that itt reports beacon Entered and Exited continuously where the user never left the beacon zone.

My code snippet

```
public class BackgroundBeaconScan extends Service implements BootstrapNotifier, BeaconConsumer {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppUtils.isBGServiceActive = true;
        //AppUtils.appTerminated = false;
        Log.e("Beacon", "Service Start");
        Log.e("Bfpk", " *** Beacon  Service is started *** ");
        LoggingOperations logger = new LoggingOperations();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(logger);
        mBeaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        try {
            Log.e("BG", "iam in mBeaconManager to unbind it");
            mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
            mBeaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
            mBeaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers();
            mBeaconManager.removeMonitoreNotifier(this);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Log.e("BG", "iam in mBeaconManager to unbind it excep ");

        }
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    //set Beacon Layout for Eddystone-UID packet


    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    //   rideBDD = new RideBDD(getApplicationContext());
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(20001);

    mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(50001);

    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(20001);

    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(50001);

    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);

    mBeaconManager.setDebug(true);

    BeaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    namespace = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID_NAME_SPACE);
    instanceID = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID_INSTANCE_ID);
    Log.e("BG", "namespace :" + namespace);
    Log.e("BG", "instanceID :" + instanceID);
    Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String time = formateLongToOnlyDateForServer(currentTime);
    LoggingOperations.writeToFile(BackgroundBeaconScan.this,"UUID > " + time + " -- > " + namespace + " - " + instanceID);



    try {
        Log.e("BG", "iam in mBeaconManager.isBound");
        mBeaconManager.bind(this);
        Log.e("BG", "iam in mBeaconManager.bind");

    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Log.e("BG", "iam in mBeaconManager.bindexce", e);

    }


}
```

My service connect

```
@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        // String preiBeaconUUID = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID);
        // postiBeaconUUID=AppUtils.addDashes(preiBeaconUUID);
        Region region;
        try {
            Log.e("BG", "iam in onBeaconServiceConnect");
            namespace = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID_NAME_SPACE);

            instanceID = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID_INSTANCE_ID);

            Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = Identifier.parse(namespace);

            Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = Identifier.parse(instanceID);

            region = new Region("EdstUIDAdvertising", myBeaconNamespaceId, myBeaconInstanceId, null);

            mBeaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
            Log.e("BG", "iam in startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BG", "iam in startMonitoringBeaconsInRegionExce" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            namespace = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID_NAME_SPACE);

            instanceID = DataHandler.getStringPreferences(AppConstants.UUID_INSTANCE_ID);

            Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = Identifier.parse(namespace);

            /* Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = Identifier.parse(instanceID);*/
            region = new Region("EdstUIDAdvertising", myBeaconNamespaceId, null, null);
            mBeaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
            Log.e("BG", "iam in startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion");

        }
        AppUtils.isBGServiceActive = true;
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mBeaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.e("Monitored", "entered"); this fires at the same time
                enterCount++;

}

  @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.e("Monitored", "exited"); // this fires at the same time

}

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

            }
        });
}
```

The

#### Mobile device model and OS version

Samsung note 5 (7.0) s6 (6.0) s5 (5.0) every device

#### Android Beacon Library version

2.12.4 // please help i am facing this issue for quiet a long time now

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem caused by *intermittent* detection of beacons.  Understand that the library only knows when a beacon disappears (exits the region) when it hasn't been detected in a long time.  The library fires  region exit event if a previously seen beacon is not seen for at least 10 seconds when the scan period ends.

Recommendations:

1. Increase your beacon transmission rate to 10 Hz or more.
2. If you cannot do (1), lengthen the scanPeriod to be longer until the problem goes away.

The problem you are experiencing is likely exacerbated by the custom scanning periods set in the example code, which shows a scanPeriod of 5 seconds followed by a betweenScanPeriod of 20 seconds.  If a beacon in the vicinity fails to be detected during the 5 second scanPeriod.

It's unclear why your beacons are not being detected sometimes during a 5 seconds scan you have configured.  It may be that they only transmit infrequently.  Some beacons send out an advertising packet only every 5 seconds or so to save battery.  If this is the case, it would certainly cause the problem you describe.  Even if they were set up to transmit once per second, it is sometimes possible that 5 packets in a row could be missed due to radio noise.

If you use the library's default settings it is less likely to happen because scanning is performed constantly in the foreground (making it much more likely that the beacon will be detected before an exit fires) and for 10 seconds in the background.  If you cannot or do not want to increase the advertising rate of your beacons, I recommend adjusting your scanPeriod / betweenScanPeriod settings to be longer than 5 seconds every 30 seconds.

For proper operation of the library, the scan period must be at least 5x the beacon transmission period. This is because not all bluetooth packets get received due to radio noise. Having an interval that is 5x the transmission period means that there are 5 chances to receive a packet on each background scan cycle, making it very unlikely the library will miss one

Comment: Thanks david, so what should be the desired params in my case 30s scan-p and 10sec -btw-scan ? and i m using your lib with a foreground service  it will work the same with the background service? and in my code all the other settings are fine or any other recommendations? considering i m using your lib 24/7 because of my rare use case.

Comment: I would limit high power scanning to a maximum of about 3000 seconds a day to save battery.  If you set the scan period to 10 seconds, then  the between scan period can be 300 secs (300000 millis).  This is equivalent to the library's default background scan intervals.

Comment: Thanks, high power scan ? 
      
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(300000L);
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(300000L);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(300000L);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(150000L);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);

These intervals i used but still faced frequent loss even so that beacon wasn't detect for 20 mins where as the beacon was active on iBKS tools config.
If you can kindly get me some programatic example of my use case i'll open source my scanning class for the rest:)

Comment: If you aren't detecting a beacon for 20 minutes with these settings then something else is wrong.   You might check for system level log messages to see if anything is blocking your scans.

Comment: Thanks allot for your help david, P.S i didn't want to open another thread so just wanted to know if you guys are planning for android O and developing any foreground version of this lib?I have read your blog post about O but that is for background which is not feasible to us so why not we use a foreground service to have the exact results? Thanks. P.S in android 7.0 when you turn the screen OFF the lib fires exit methods right there with default scan intervals do check that out.

Comment: Android 7 blocks scanning for more than 30 minutes.   You can overcome this with the library using the instructions here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/529  For Android 8, long scanning in the foreground is already allowed.  You may create your own foreground service and simply start a foreground scan with the library so it runs continually.